# Toggling between QMdiArea windows changes view

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside

I'm making a Qt based GUI using Python/PySide for viewing and comparing images. For this I'm using a `QMdiArea` with several `QMdiSubWindows`. Each `QMdiSubWindow` has a QGraphicsView as its central widget. I want to view a time series of images, visually comparing them by Ctrl-Tabbing between the subwindows.

My problem is that if I maximize the `QSubWindows` and try to Ctrl-Tab between them, it works as expected when switching from SubWindow 1 to SubWindow 2. However, when I Ctrl-Tab back to SubWindow 1, the viewport changes by a few pixels. That is, every time I switch to a different subwindow and back again the scrollbar moves to the left, making the image shift a little to the right.

This is only an issue when the subwindows are maximized. If I tile them things work as expected.
Any idea why this is happening (feature or bug)?
An how would I keep it from happening? Do I need to manually keep track of the view rectangle or scrollbar values?

This is a minimal working example:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self._mdiArea = QtGui.QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._mdiArea)

        self._scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('/path/to/veryLargImage(12000x12000).tif')

        self._scene.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.black, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        self._scene.addPixmap(pixmap)

        for i in range(2):
            win = SubWindow('Image {}'.format(i), scene=self._scene)
            self._mdiArea.addSubWindow(win)

        self.showMaximized()

class SubWindow(QtGui.QMdiSubWindow):

    def __init__(self, title='', scene=None, parent=None):
        super(SubWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self._view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
        self.setWidget(self._view)

        # Connect a scene to the view
        self._view.setScene(scene)
        self._view.setWindowTitle(title)

        self.setWindowTitle(title)


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I also see this behavior and think it is unwanted and rather a bug. You might have to workaround manually. Like listening to focus change events of sub windows and keeping the scroll area constant there. Kind of annoying for an image comparing application.